# PHP/MySql How to convert dateTime from STRING to DATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to insert some data to my database. The data contains also one date and time. So I need to insert that by converting into MySql DateTime format. I tried by using `STR_TO_DATE`, But it returns `Date and Time Without AM OR PM`.

Code Executed :

```
$sql = "INSERT into `projtemp` (`user_id`,`temp_name`,`processes`,`added`) VALUES('$uid','" . clean_data($tempName) . "','" . serialize($process) . "',STR_TO_DATE('$added', '%e/%c/%Y %r'))";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die("Sql Error :" . $mysqli->error);
```

Query :

```
INSERT INTO `projtemp` (`user_id`,`temp_name`,`processes`,`added`) VALUES('0000000001','dsfwfwrfer','a:5:{i:0;s:11:"rgergergerg";i:1;s:29:"software requirement analysis";i:2;s:8:"regergre";i:3;s:16:"eqgerrrrrrrrrger";i:4;s:14:"ergergggggrreg";}',STR_TO_DATE('15/1/2014 11:34:21 AM', '%e/%c/%Y %r'))
```

Resultant Row :

[image]

I referred [This Site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), In that they says `%r` appends `AM` Or `PM` to `Time` But it didn't worked for me. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: @ peterm See the query given in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For date without am/pm:

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($added));
```

With am/pm:

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s A", strtotime($added));
```

Finally your SQL stament will be:

```
$sql = "INSERT into `projtemp` (`user_id`,`temp_name`,`processes`,`added`) VALUES('$uid','" . clean_data($tempName) . "','" . serialize($process) . "','".$datetime."')";
```

For more details on date function refer: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
***Note:** If your column is of dataype `datetime` it won't insert am/pm with the date.

Comment: Then what should I do if I want to insert `AM` Or `PM`

Comment: you have to change it to `varchar`  then.

Comment: Your statement returns `0000-00-00 00:00:00` when I run.

Comment: When you are already having this string in date time format with am/pm then why you want it to convert again into datetime?

Comment: I wanted to convert because I used the `datatype` as `datetime` now I changed that to `varchar` but still I have problem with your code. If I pass `15/1/2014 12:49:53` it returns `1970-01-01 01:00:00 AM`.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Why it is producing the wrong result is, the input should be in this `15-1-2014 13:12:23` format. Now it is working well. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($added);
```

Then convert it to timestamp/datetime format using date(),

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s A", $timestamp);
```